# How can I see the json coming from the client when using Spring-MVC?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, debugging

A client software is trying to access my Spring-MVC rest server, but it's getting a 400 (Bad Request) response every time. I know my server is fine (it's in use by many other clients), but I cannot debug the client application, so I cannot see what it is sending.

Is there a way for me to see what JSON I am receiving before Spring tries to convert it to an entity and fails? It's okay if I can only do this at debug time, I just need to be able to give support to this application's creators.

Just in case, here is the spring-mvc controller method:

```
@Named
@RequestMapping(value = "/taskmanager/task")
public class TaskManagerTaskRest {
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void createTask(@RequestBody Task task, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws CalabacinException {
        // This code never gets executed because the Task json is invalid, but I don't know how I could see it.
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and use a [AbstractRequestLoggingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html) filter implementation and conditionally log the relevant parts of the request. You should use [ContentCachingRequestWrapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html) to wrap the request.

Comment: Good answer. I will be able to see what I'm receiving and log it (or debug it), which is what I asked for, but for those of you trying this, if you read the request body in a filter you will consume the InputStream from the request; and as a consequence Spring will ALWAYS fail when it tries to parse that InputStream's json again to convert it to an entity.

Comment: Not if you wrap the request - I've edited my answser

Comment: I've chosen this answer as valid because it tells me how to do what I want programmatically, and that is useful information. Also Fiddler didn't even work for me; I had to use Wireshark

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). It will help you to catch HTTP requests/responses. You will be able to see your JSON.

Comment: yes, you can use fiddler as a reverse proxy, http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the best solution. It doesn't require any programming or tampering, just watch as the connection is made and see everything you need.

Comment: Then this question is not about Spring MVC, but a general question about proxying requests.

Comment: Fiddler didn't even work. I had to use Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) in the end. I'm choosing the other answer as valid because it tells me how to do what I ask using Java code, and I find that very useful.

I still voted this question positively.